# IEqualityComparer to get distinct tuples excluding tuple items that are null

Tags: c#, linq

I have implemented an IEqualityComparer on a Distinct LINQ sequence. I want to get distinct Tuples excluding Tuples with a null in any of the two items.

But it still includes results with a null value in Tuple. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
var types = numbers.Select(x => (x.Model, x.Values).Distinct(new TupleElementTypeComparer());

class TupleElementTypeComparer : IEqualityComparer<(Model, Values)>
{
    public bool Equals((Model, Values) x, (Model, Values) y)
    {
        // Make sure that not any of the values are null. Return true such that distinct removes null
        if (x.Item1 == null || y.Item1 == null) return true;
        if (x.Item2 == null || y.Item2 == null) return true;
        if (x.Item2.Area == null || y.Item2.Area == null) return true;

        return x.Item2.Id.Equals(y.Item2.Id);
    }

    public int GetHashCode((Model, Values) obj)
    {
        return (obj.Item1 == null || obj.Item2 == null) ? 0 : obj.Item2.Id;
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want tuples which contain a `null` to be removed by `Distinct` entirely? `Distinct` doesn't do that

Comment: Yes, I was hoping to use the GetHashCode to manipulate Distinct

Comment: `Distinct` will find items which are the same as other items and remove them. Unless you pretend that your tuples with `null` values are the same as some other element in the collection, and convince `Distinct` to take the other element (it's not obliged to take any specific element out of a set of identical ones), it's not going to do what you want. If you want to filter out tuples with `null` values, add a `.Where` which removes tuples with `null` values

Comment: @canton7 Fair enough - I was hoping for another solution than a `.Where` cause of performance. But it seems I need to settle with it.

Comment: If you're that worried about performance, you shouldn't be using Linq in the first place. Write your own code which does exactly what you want, without the overhead of Linq. As always, profile!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Distinct` cannot remove something out of existence. That's what `Where` is for. Conventional wisdom would be to add one before the `Select` or before the `Distinct`. You could also add it after `Distinct`, because it will compact all undesired items into one. Not sure what would be more efficient. If speed is an issue run some performance tests for both solutions.

EDIT: Also, I think there is an error in your current code. You check if `Item2.Area` is null in `Equals`, but not in `GetHashCode`. Without a `Where` clause (maybe if you use `TupleElementTypeComparer` elsewhere in code) `Distinct` would not work properly for null `Area` items.